# Write-ups/Tutorials on PHP for ASP.NET developers?

Tags: php, asp.net

There's a good 2-part series on [ASP.NET for PHP Developers](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/asp-net/asp-net-for-php-developers/) on http://net.tutsplus.com which is the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Is anyone familiar with something similar going the other direction, PHP for ASP.NET developers?

I know there is lots of information out there for PHP but I like the format for the article above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, but worth noting. I've found that looking at source code for existing projects can be a valuable resource. To that end, try [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Drupal](http://drupal.org/), or even [Wordpress](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/). I'm partial to Cake, myself, so maybe try reading [this article](http://debuggable.com/posts/learning-from-the-cakephp-source-code-part-i:480f4dd6-28d0-445e-a1dc-4ceacbdd56cb) which answers the question of WHY, oh why, you'd tinker with existing/working code :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with Drupal/Wordpress and have heard of CakePHP,  http://tv.cakephp.org/ looks like a good starting point.